# SQL Server 2008 SELECT top 3 based on GROUP result of distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a couple tables:

Table A.

```
id | Extra Columns | report ID
---+---------------+----------
 1 | datetime      | 1
 2 | datetime      | 3
 3 | datetime      | 4
 4 | datetime      | 1
 5 | datetime      | 1
```

Table B.

```
Report id | customer ID|
----------+------------+
 1        | Joe        |
 2        | Joe        |
 3        | Joe        |
 4        | Joe        |
 1        | Sally      |
 2        | Sally      |
 3        | Sally      |
```

What i'd like to do is select N entries (if they exist) from Table A For each Report belonging to Customer "Joe", which is cross-referenced in Table B. The output should look something like this:

```
id | datetime | report ID
---+----------+----------
 1 | datetime | 1
 4 | datetime | 1
 5 | datetime | 1
 2 | datetime | 3
 3 | datetime | 4
```

Of Note, there are many other support tables that i will be Joining to pull data but these two are are giving me a headache. Table A is enormous but runs an index over the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` here to number the matching reports for the customer Joe, and then retain the first N reports.  In the query below, I retain the first 3 though you can change this value.

```
SELECT t.id, t.[Extra Columns], t.[report ID]
FROM
(
    SELECT a.id, a.[Extra Columns], a.[report ID],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.[customer ID] ORDER BY b.[Report ID]) rn
    FROM tableB b
    INNER JOIN tableA a
        ON b.[Report id] = a.[report ID]
    WHERE b.[customer ID] = 'Joe'
) t
WHERE t.rn <= 3
ORDER BY t.[report ID]
```

Comment: Ty, you saved me so much time. I actually tried partitioning but not over row numbers.

Comment: Happy to help you out.